# Runas command Access denied

Tags: batch-file, runas

I want to run a program from startup by a batch file in startup folder, the file says this:

runas.exe /savecred /"user:pedro burgos" "%cd%\test.bat"

But, the problem is that when I run this and enter my password, it says Error 5: Access denied

Can anyone help me pls?

Answer (score 4):

Found this in another forum.

Feel like a dumbass now, but do use caution, and get more info.

The `runas` command depends on the **Secondary Logon** service.
On my system, it is by default set to manual, and it is not activated.

AFAIK, this is a legacy feature, so that is probably the reason why it is not running.

EDIT:
*It's legacy, because this command predates UAC; MS would like you to use UAC instead of `runas`, which is safer; you can trigger a UAC prompt by calling scripts in PowerShell with `-Verb RunAs` argument*

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue as you on Server 2019, secondary logon service on manual. Your initial answer seemed to be the solution but it wasn't. On server 2019 the secondary logon service is on manual by default and will start automatic if you are using a run as command.

The answer was as is upgraded the server 2019 edition that the local system account didn't have the correct rights to engage with the secondary logon service.

Resolved the issue with this MS article (article is for server 2012)
Start CMD as administrator;

```
sc sdset seclogon D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPDTLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWDTLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPDTLOCRRC;;;AU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
runas.exe /savecred /user:"pedro burgos" "%cd%\test.bat"

Comment: but username usually don't have spaces

Comment: I think the error is about access permisions, because it accepts the password, but thank you for the help

Comment: you have <"> at the wrong place. and it will ask for password when it runs it. right click "this PC" select manage. go to users and groups click user and make sure the account exist. don't look at full name but the account listed the "name" column. if the account exist. it shouldn't have a space. Reset the password and you shouldn't need to use " "

Comment: @Druskus C:\Users\pberube>runas /savecred /user:mutedsys\muteddisk cmd.exe
Attempting to start cmd.exe as user "mutedsys\muteddisk" ...
Enter the password for mutedsys\muteddisk:
Attempting to start cmd.exe as user "mutedsys\muteddisk" ...

C:\Users\pberube>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure user "pedro burgos" actually has access to that directory. For example, one user can't just access other user's directories. You can test this theory by moving the script to something like C:\temp